# Работа с именованными объектами

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Для решения задачи комивояжера использую массивы из библиотеки NumPy:

```
    mat = np.array([[-1., 10., 25., 25., 10.],
                    [1., -1, 10., 15., 2.],
                    [8., 9., -1., 20., 10.],
                    [14., 10., 24., -1., 15.],
                    [10., 8., 25., 27., -1.]])
```

Столбцы и строки представляют собой именованные точки (города). Алгоритм работы предполагает периодическое удаление некоторых строк и столбцов. При этом теряется информация об оставшихся именованных столбцах и строках.
Приходится параллельно вести два вектора (по столбцам и строкам), к которым применяются аналогичные операции удаления.

Есть ли возможность использовать преимущества библиотеки NumPy (работа с массивами) и возможности DataFrame из Pandas по ведению именованных столбцов и строк?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно Pandas DataFrame и есть набор именованных Numpy векторов (столбцы таблицы). Кроме этого у DataFrame есть индекс - метка или имя каждой строки.

Таким образом Pandas DataFrame обеспечивает удобное индексирование как по строкам так и по столбцам.

Большинство алгоритмов и функций умеющих работать с Numpy матрицами могут напрямую работать с Pandas DataFrame.

> Приходится параллельно вести два вектора (по столбцам и строкам), к
>   которым применяются аналогичные операции удаления.

Pandas делает это за вас автоматически. Если вам нужен доступ к меткам / именам строк или столбцов то воспользуйтесь атрибутами:

```
df.index
```

или

```
df.columns
```

соответственно.